# how to add/update url parameter on change of select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 1 `select` option box, in that I have 3 options, If user select any option then in url that option's particular value should get appended like(`value=needbyDate`) & when I select another option then whatever option value it was there in url which was selected earlier, it should get replaced with new option value. kindly help. for now with my code all values are getting appended one after another but as per the expectations only one value should get appended at a time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#optionbox1").change(function() {
        var optionValue = $(this).val();
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") > 0) {
          window.location += "options added=" + optionValue;
        } else {
          window.location += "?options added=" + optionValue;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="optionbox1">
      <option value="needbyDate">needbyDate</option>
      <option value="needbyNumber">needbyNumber</option>
      <option value="needbyPOnumber">needbyPOnumber</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the *url* with `?` and use the string from first *index*:

```
$("#optionbox1").change(function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).val();
    var url = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") > 0) {
      window.location = url + "options added=" + optionValue;
    } else {
      window.location = url + "?options added=" + optionValue;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Understand your concern. I've done one line change which helps you to achieve your requirements. I've used here split() of jQuery.

```
I've mentioned the change in bold. Please find change as below.


if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") > 0) {
          ***window.location  = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "?options added=" + optionValue;***
} else {
          window.location += "?options added=" + optionValue;
}
```

Comment: *jquery* has a split method?

Answer (score 0):

Use simply this without using checking "?".

```
$("#optionbox1").change(function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).val();
  var url = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('');
window.location = url+"?options added=" + optionValue;
});
```